# display search results in windows forms data grid view

Tags: c#, winforms

im trying to set up a form on windows forms
that has search box and a data grid view
is it possible to display search results in the data grid view
when the search value will be taken from the textbox.

please advise

Comment: Don't try, just do it. And if you have specific problem (e.g. [click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9593425/1997232) or [click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20102982/1997232)), only then we can help.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes.

Answer (score 0):

get data from Database based on search Value and store it List and bind it in GridView

http://tech.pro/tutorial/776/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx